# Is there a way to use dynamic data ranges in GoogleSheet equations, to adapt to imported csv data?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet which data is imported from a CSV. Then, the spreadsheet does basic calculations and graphs

The issue is that the number of rows and columns are not always the same, so the next import from the same csv might result in data with a different number of rows and columns.

**Importing CSV**

I tried to use `IMPORTDATA("URL")` so I don't have to manually import the file each time but it does not seem to work with local files

**Adapting the graphs and calculation data ranges**

Is there a way to tell the equation/graph ranges to dynamically adapt to the imported data range?

Thanks

Comment: Consider using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

Comment: I will check it. thanks